# How to add windows credentials to an apache camel route?

Tags: apache, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x, credentials

I need to authenticate myself when I want to access a REST api.

I have created a simple example with apache's `WinHttpClients` which works and also accepts a self signed `crt` which is used by that site.

These are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.+'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-win:4.5.+'

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

And this is the working code (authorization works, acceptance of crt works)

```
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (WinHttpClients.isWinAuthAvailable()) {
      PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager httpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
        buildSSLSocketFactory());
      HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = WinHttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties();
      clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(httpClientConnectionManager);
      CloseableHttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();

      HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost("server.evilcorp.com", 443, "https");
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
        "/evilwebapi/streams/endpointalpha/data");
      httpGet.setHeader("accept", "application/json");

      CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpHost, httpGet);

      String content = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
      System.out.println(content); // returns expected json result
    }
  }

  private static Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> buildSSLSocketFactory() {
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(buildSSLContext(), NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
    return RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
      .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
      .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
      .build();
  }

  private static SSLContext buildSSLContext() {
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    try {
      sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, (TrustStrategy) (arg0, arg1) -> true).build();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException e) {
      System.out.println("Failed to initialize SSL handling.\n" + e);
    }
    return sslContext;
  }
}
```

When I try to access the same site through apache camel I get a `401` status.

I tried to configure camel's `httpComponent` in various ways but so far I can't make authentication work. This is the current camel setup.

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.18.+'
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-sql:2.18.+'
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-http4:2.18.+'
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-jetty:2.18.+'
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:2.18.+'
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-guava-eventbus:2.18.+'
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-quartz2:2.18.+'
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.+'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.+'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-win:4.5.+'
  testRuntime files('src/test/resources')
  runtime files('src/main/resources')
}
```

And this is the `RouteBuilder` which does not work (authorization doesm't works, statusCode: 401)

```
context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:model.properties");
context.addComponent("properties", pc);
try {

  context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
      HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
      httpComponent.setHttpClientConfigurer(new WinHttpClientConfigurer());
      httpComponent.setClientConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(WinHttpClientConfigurer.buildSSLSocketFactory()));
      httpComponent.setHttpConfiguration(buildHttpConfiguration());
      getContext().getProperties().put("CamelJacksonEnableTypeConverter", "true");
      getContext().getProperties().put("CamelJacksonTypeConverterToPojo", "true");

      from("quartz2://pipull?cron=0+0/1+*+1/1+*+?+*")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,
            simple("start='${header.start}'&end='${header.end}'"))
        .multicast().parallelProcessing()
        .to("direct:model");

      from("direct:model")
        .setHeader("contractRef", simple("${properties:model.name}"))
        .to("https4://server.evilcorp.com/evilwebapi/streams/endpointalpha/data")
        .to("direct:transform");

      from("direct:transform").unmarshal()
        .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Model.class)
        .bean(ProcessorImpl.class)
        .to("guava-eventbus:botBus");
      }

      private HttpConfiguration buildHttpConfiguration() {
        WindowsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new WindowsCredentialsProvider(
          new SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider());
        Credentials credentials = credentialsProvider.getCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1, null, AuthSchemes.NTLM));
        HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConfiguration.setAuthMethod(AuthSchemes.NTLM);
        httpConfiguration.setAuthUsername(credentials.getUserPrincipal().getName());

        return httpConfiguration;
      }

    });
    context.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    isRunning.set(false);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
```

Comment: Given that you are using NTLM, do you need to do preemptive authentication? Have you tried the Camel route against a test server to see what headers the Camel endpoint is sending? Do you see Camel sending the authorization header?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem through subtyping `HttpComponent` and adding that to the camel context.

```
public class WinHttpComponent extends HttpComponent {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WinHttpComponent.class);

  public WinHttpComponent() {
    this(HttpEndpoint.class);
  }

  public WinHttpComponent(Class<? extends HttpEndpoint> endpointClass) {
    super(endpointClass);
  }

  @Override protected Endpoint createEndpoint(String uri, String remaining, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
      // copy-paste everything from super method
      // replace this
      // HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
      // with this
      HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = WinHttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties();
      // copy-paste everything from super method
  }  
}

context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
context.addComponent("https4", new WinHttpComponent());
try {
  context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
      HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4", HttpComponent.class);
      // connection manager which accepts self-signed cert
      httpComponent.setClientConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
        NoopSslVerifierHttpClientConfigurer.buildSSLSocketFactory()));
      ...
      ...
      ...
    }
  }
```